# I want to play a simple audio file using python but keep on getting error

Tags: python, pygame

My Code is below :

```
from pygame import mixer
from pygame import time

def wateronloop(file, stopper): # creating a function to play the file
mixer.init()
mixer.music.load(file)
mixer.music.set_volume(0.5)
mixer.music.play()

while True:
    usin = input("To stop the music, type s") # a user input
    if usin == stopper:
        mixer.music.stop()
        break
if __name__ == '__main__':

wateronloop("water.mp3", "s") # calling the function
```

Error:

pygame.error: mpg123_seek: Invalid RVA mode. (code 12)

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Did you try](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/) to [copy and paste the error message into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=pygame.error%3A+mpg123_seek%3A+Invalid+RVA+mode.+(code+12))?

Answer (score 0):

The reason this can happen is that the mp3 was compressed or converted from another file type. I would try to convert it to a different format and play it from the new format.

The code you wrote should work - assuming the indentation is okay. It came out incorrect on this question.